# knitr fails to knit UTF-8 characters: "These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters"

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, knitr

I try to knit a RMD file that contains UTF-8 characters.

The file looks as simple as this one:

```
test with some characters: ü ö ä ß
```

The command to knit looks like this

```
library(knitr)
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
knitr::knit2html("FILE_LOCATION/UTF file.Rmd",  output="Output_File.html")
```

it fails however: the file knits the text as "test with some characters: ÃƒÂ¼ ÃƒÂ¶ ÃƒÂ¤ ÃƒÅ¸"
and there is a warning:

> The file  .../UTF file.Rmd is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines
>   contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 1

However, the file *is* UTF-8 (both where the command is executed from and the RMD file). I ensured that by RStudio, save with encoding, UTF-8 (which is anyways set as standard). Interestingly, if I use a slightly different command:

```
library(knitr)
options(encoding = "native.enc")       #  Only change in this line
knitr::knit2html("FILE_LOCATION/UTF file.Rmd",  output="Output_File.html")
```

One of my two computers knits the document correctly. The other, again, produces: "test with some characters: Ã¼ Ã¶ Ã¤ ÃŸ" without a warning. 
Strangely, both computers use Windows 10, the same version of R (R 3.5.3), RStudio (1.1.463) and knitr (tried both with the same result: 1.22 and 1.25).

Help appreciated.

Edit: added output of `xfun::session_info("knitr")`

```
> xfun::session_info("knitr")
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
  LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

Package version:
  evaluate_0.14   glue_1.3.0      graphics_3.5.1  grDevices_3.5.1 highr_0.8       knitr_1.25      magrittr_1.5   
  markdown_1.1    methods_3.5.1   mime_0.7        stats_3.5.1     stringi_1.2.4   stringr_1.3.1   tools_3.5.1    
  utils_3.5.1     xfun_0.10       yaml_2.2.0
```

Comment: You shall almost never set `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`. If you have to set it, there must be something else wrong (cf https://github.com/yihui/xfun/issues/21), and setting this option usually "fixes" one problem while introducing more problems. Could you explain why you need to set it?

Comment: Thanks for posting! Ok, I will leave `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` out. Then the problem turns to why  without `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` one machine fails to knit correctly the other succeeds. Where can I look for the difference that causes this surprising behavior?

Comment: I'm unable to answer this question since the information you provided in your post is too limited. You need to compare `xfun::session_info('knitr')` on the two machines. Anyway, I think if you [update your R packages](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/), the problem should go away now (because I have released a newer version of xfun to CRAN to fix https://github.com/yihui/xfun/issues/21).

Comment: Thank you again. I compared `xfun::session_info("knitr")` on the two machines and could trace the problem to the *update* of the package "markdown" from version 0.9 to 1.0  --- ie the problem occurs with the update (and is not remedied in 1.1.). This happens on all three locales (three different machines): `LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252`, `LC_COLLATE=German_German.1252` and `LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252`. I am surprised no one else has reported this before.

Comment: I'm not too surprised. As I said, setting `options(encoding = )` is often a very bad idea. The change in the **markdown** package was intentional: https://github.com/rstudio/markdown/blob/master/NEWS That said, if you [update your R packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/), this problem should be gone now (the issue in **xfun** has been fixed).

Comment: Sorry for the obvious confusion but there is a misunderstanding: `options(encoding=”native.enc”)` is the standard anyway, ie setting this is superfluous. Anyways, thanks to your suggestion to use `xfun::session_info(“knitr”)` I could track down the issue over multiple computers and versions. The  issue described arises whenever one uses markdown version => 1.0 and R version < 3.6.0 and Windows 10 (maybe other Windows versions as well, maybe R version 3.6.0 too). I post a summary solution. Thanks again.

Comment: i'm having the same issue with ` LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250` on WIndows 10, R 4.0.4, markdown 1.1 (čšž characters are causing the problem) any ideas? @YihuiXie

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Issue: knitting of special characters like “ö, ü, ß” in .RMD files (even though encoded in UTF-8) fails on Windows 10, markdown version => 1.0 and R version < 3.6.0.

Solution: update R.